# PowerShell - how can I get memory consumption peak for my exe program from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, memory-consumption

I have a program which allocates memory.
I am running it from Windows PowerShell command line. It can run for 1-2 hours allocating and releasing memory blocks.

What I am looking for is a way to get at the end (when the program finishes) some memory consumption statistics.
More specifically, what was the peak usage of the memory (max memory allocated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Process -Id xxx` gives you the [`Process` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-5.0#properties) instance of the process with ID xxx. There are all kinds of memory-related properties in there, including things like `PeakVirtualMemorySize64` and `PeakWorkingSet64`. Pick the ones you find useful.

You can even set up a background job to get a data series, something like

```
$proc = Start-Process "your_long_running.exe" -PassThru

$memoryWatcher = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    while ($true) {
        Get-Process -Id $args[0] | Select VirtualMemorySize64,PeakVirtualMemorySize64
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
} -ArgumentList $proc.Id

# now wait for the process to end
Wait-Process -Id $proc.Id
    
$memoryWatcher.StopJob()
$results = Receive-Job $memoryWatcher

$results | Format-Table
```